# Embedded automatic full text indexing completely removed from Neo4j as of 3.0.0?

Tags: neo4j

I'm moving from Neo4j 2.2.* to (still prerelease) 3.0.0 and all of a sudden it seems that configuration parameters

```
node_auto_indexing=true
relationship_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=some_node_property
relationship_keys_indexable=some_rel_property
```

had gone and are not available any more. This is sad because I need full-text indexing (namely, fuzzy search queries and range searches), I was happily using it since 2.0.0 and had a naive hope that new Lucene 5.5 will make my life better with 3.0.0.

Is this functionality completely removed? START clause is still here in Cypher, neo4j-shell still has command which allows manipulating "legacy" FT indices so my question is:

how do I populate my FT index without using Java or another external programming language?

- case 1: I import some bunch of "static" data into the graph which
  will rarely be updated (consider dictionary) and need to arrange FTS
  on those once, and manually perform complete reindex on occasional updates of the dataset;
- case 2: nodes and relationships with specific properties
  automagically get indexed upon creation or upon assignment of a new value to the property with specific name, near-realtime, as it used to be before.

New schema indexes are cool in 3.0.0 and range searches are implemented, but a) they work only on properties of nodes, no relationships, b) they don't allow full-text, fuzzy queries, and AFAIK regular expression matching does not use index.

Thanks for your suggestions!
WBR, Andrii

Answer (score 0):

Andrii,

only the default config parameters have been removed not the functionality.

What is the actual use-case you are using the FTS indexes (on rels) for?

In 3.0 you can still use the start-clause but using stored procedures you can add nodes and relationship explicitly to indexes. And you can use similar procedures to query your indexes even more efficiently, e.g. by passing in start and end-nodes.

See (WIP): https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-apoc-procedures#manual-indexes

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you for the answer. So I got the idea that I can explicitly use  stored procedures to fill my FT index, Ok.
But the question is, are configuration parameters above supposed to work inside neo4j.conf at 3.0?

Comment: One more question. How do I know (without reading Java source) what exactly is available for me to YIELD from the procedure call? Shall I just rely on the published description of the procedure, which ultimately tells me, what the name of YIELDed value exactly is, and I shall not expect anything different?